# Forçar download com Header não funciona no PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, download, header

Eu uso esse código para forçar download, ele funciona perfeito quando rodo ele no XAMPP, porem ele retorna arquivo corrompido quando executo no ubunto, oque posso fazer para arrumar?

```
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesizecurl($file_path));
        header('Content-Type: "application/zip"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($new_name).'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        // Envia o arquivo para o cliente
        readfile($file_path);
```